# Open PDF with Photoshop using Python

Tags: python, photoshop

I would like to open a PDF in Photoshop using Python. I know how to open photoshop (.psd) files using python, but I am wondering if there is a way to specify the program used to open a file.

So far, all I do to open a photoshop document is:

```
psd = "path\to\photoshop\document"
os.startfile(psd)
```

but when I use os.startfile on a PDF it opens with Adobe Acrobat. I'd like to open the PDF in photoshop instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't use just use ``subprocess.call()`` to execute Photoshop and pass in the pdf as a parameter?

Comment: @BeRecursive can you start photoshop from the command line like that?

Comment: would the environment variables' Path have to have the path to the photoshop directory? I tried adding it and then tried opening photoshop using the command line and it didn't work.

Comment: @cms_mgr I haven't got Photoshop on this computer, but don't see why ``cmd /c "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Photoshop.exe"`` wouldn't work from Run

Comment: So something like ``subprocess.call("C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CS4/Photoshop.exe", "C:/mypdf.pdf")``

Comment: I tried this:    
ps = "C:\Path\To\Photoshop"
pdf = "C:\Path\To\PDF"
subprocess.call(ps, pdf)

and I get: "TypeError: bufsize must be an integer."
Sorry for poor formatting...

Comment: try `subprocess.call([ps,pdf])`

Answer (score 1):

```
from comtypes.client import GetActiveObject

# Start up Photoshop application
# app = Dispatch('Photoshop.Application')

# Or get Reference to already running Photoshop application instance
app = GetActiveObject("Photoshop.Application")
fileName = "C:\Git\PS_Samples_Files\MyPDFFile.pdf"
docRef = app.Open(fileName)
```

More examples at https://github.com/lohriialo/photoshop-scripting-python

Answer (score 0):

`os.startfile` just starts the specified file [with its default application](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile). Changing the default application for PDFs to photoshop would get the result you want, but at the cost of making opening PDFs in other circumstances really annoying.

To do this properly you'd need to script it using photshop's COM interface. I haven't tried that but [this tutorial](http://techarttiki.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html) looks like if might fit your needs.

Comment: What about that [operation] option? Is it possible to set it to 'Open With...' and then specify Photoshop?

Comment: No that doesn't look like valid input from looking at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has options in opening a PDF document, called `Photoshop.PDFOpenOptions`

You need win32com to dispatch the photoshop application. See sample code below

```
import win32com.client
import os, glob
folderin = r'D:\in'
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.Application')
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(folderin, '*.pdf')):
            options = win32com.client.Dispatch('Photoshop.PDFOpenOptions')
            options.CropPage = 0   # BoundingBox
            options.Resolution = 300   # Pixels
            options.Mode = 1    # Grayscale
            options.BitsPerChannel = 8  # 8 bits per channel
            options.AntiAlias = True
            options.ConstrainProportions = True #Deprecated for Adobe Photoshop CS3

            doc = psApp.Open(infile, options)
            doc.flatten
            doc.Trim(1)
            doc.Close(2)

    psApp.Quit()
```